# SQL Oracle, MySQL, SQLite Standards

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite

This is puzzling me.  I have written standard sequel that works in MySQL and SQLite but in Oracle indicates I am missing a right parenthesis.  Please explain.

```
create table department(
   dept_name var char(20) not null, 
   building var char(15) not null, 
   budget numeric(12, 2),
   primary key(dept_name)
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `varchar` type should not have a space in it:

```
create table department(
   dept_name varchar(20) not null, -- Note: varchar, not var char
   building varchar(15) not null, -- same here
   budget numeric(12, 2),
   primary key(dept_name)
);
```

Comment: Weird .. I originally types var char as varchar but Oracle underlined it as if there was a problem with the spelling of the type but accepts var char.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` types are currently synonymous but future versions of oracle may change this (For `VARCHAR2` a zero length string is identical to `NULL` but when the `VARCHAR` type is implemented then a zero-length `VARCHAR` will not be identical to `NULL`). You probably want to use `VARCHAR2` rather than `VARCHAR`